# Using SQL alias statement in SELECT query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been trying to get this access query to work, I'm learning to write SQL so I wanted to try using alias's for my table to make it easier to use but for some reason I keep getting errors. Here is my original SQL query

```
SELECT qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.Utility
    ,qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.MeterID
    ,qryLastYearAvgMtrHis.AvgOfUnits AS LYRAvgOfUnits
    ,qryLastYearMtrHis.Units AS LYRUnits
    ,qryLastMonthMtrHis.Units AS PrevMonUnits
    ,qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.Units AS CurrentUnits
    ,qryLastYearAvgMtrHis.AvgOfTotCost
    ,qryLastYearMtrHis.TotCost AS LYRTotCost
    ,qryLastMonthMtrHis.TotCost AS PrevMonTotCost
    ,qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.TotCost AS CurrentTotCost
FROM qryLastYearMtrHis
RIGHT JOIN (
    qryLastYearAvgMtrHis RIGHT JOIN (
        qryLastMonthMtrHis RIGHT JOIN qryCurrentMonthMtrHis ON (qryLastMonthMtrHis.Utility = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.Utility)
            AND (qryLastMonthMtrHis.MeterID = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.MeterID)
        ) ON (qryLastYearAvgMtrHis.Utility = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.Utility)
        AND (qryLastYearAvgMtrHis.MeterID = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.MeterID)
    ) ON (qryLastYearMtrHis.Utility = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.Utility)
    AND (qryLastYearMtrHis.MeterID = qryCurrentMonthMtrHis.MeterID);
```

And here is the one I'm trying to do with alias

```
    SELECT cm.Utility
    ,cm.MeterID
    ,lyra.AvgOfUnits AS LYRAvgOfUnits
    ,lyr.Units AS LYRUnits
    ,pm.Units AS PrevMonUnits
    ,cm.Units AS CurrentUnits
    ,lyra.AvgOfTotCost
    ,lyr.TotCost AS LYRTotCost
    ,pm.TotCost AS PrevMonTotCost
    ,cm.TotCost AS CurrentTotCost
FROM qrylastYearMtrHis lyr
RIGHT JOIN (
    qryLastYearAvgMtrHis lyra RIGHT JOIN (
        qryLastMonthMtrHis pm RIGHT JOIN qryCurrentMonthMtrHis cm ON (lyr.Utility = cm.Utility)
            AND (pm.MeterID = cm.MeterID)
        ) ON (lyra.Utility = cm.Utility)
        AND (lyra.MeterID = cm.MeterID)
    ) ON (lyr.Utility = cm.Utility)
    AND (lyr.MeterID = cm.MeterID);
```

When I try to run the second one though, it says "syntax error in join operation" and highlights the "lyr" in lyra.AvgOfUnits. From what I've read online it should be working, so I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight?

Comment: Something I haven't been able to find online but might be the problem, can you not alias a query in another query? Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Does the first one run ok?

Comment: Yes it creates exactly what I need. I just need to do some calculations in the same query, and if I don't have alias's for the different query names the query will get huge and unwieldy, and also I want to improve my SQL skills, so that's why I'm trying to use alias's and not just using the first one as is.

Comment: I think the column name alias's are fine since they work in the first query, I think it's the table name alias's where a problem is being created.

Comment: You're the first one who actually uses this  `table 
    join table 
    join table 
    join table 
    on 
    on 
    on`

syntax instead of 

   `table 
    join table 
    on 
    join table 
    on 
    join table 
    on`

(plus RIGHT instead of LEFT joins)

Is there a specific reason why you prefer this?

Comment: @dnoeth I'm working in MS access, and that was the way it was designed in the original query design. I usually make the basic query structure in query design in access, and then switch to SQL to add in things I want. But it works as table join table join table join table on on on so I leave it like that. Is there a reason to change it if it is already created like that? I'm a beginner, so I claim no great knowledge of the best ways to code.

Comment: No, it's just a syntax variation. I couldn't write it like this, it's easier for me to follow the logic the other way :-) And most people also prefer LEFT joins because they read from left to right and so they can start with the most important table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a wrong alias in a join:

```
RIGHT JOIN (
    qryLastYearAvgMtrHis lyra RIGHT JOIN (
        qryLastMonthMtrHis pm RIGHT JOIN qryCurrentMonthMtrHis cm ON (lyr.Utility = cm.Utility)
```

Must be `pm.Utility`instead of `lyr.Utility`.

Didn't you use a search&replace?

Comment: No I did it manually, and that was my problem. Thank you! I can't believe I did/missed something so stupid! Thank you guys!

Comment: @hypetech Always search and replace, use notepad++ or something

Comment: You're right, that was my bad. I'm still a beginner with queries so I thought there was just a problem with my coding, not that I missed something so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cm.Utility, cm.MeterID, lyra.AvgOfUnits AS LYRAvgOfUnits, lyr.Units AS LYRUnits,
       pm.Units AS PrevMonUnits, cm.Units AS CurrentUnits, lyra.AvgOfTotCost, 
       lyr.TotCost AS LYRTotCost, pm.TotCost AS PrevMonTotCost, 
       cm.TotCost AS CurrentTotCost
FROM qryLastYearMtrHis lyr 
RIGHT JOIN (qryLastYearAvgMtrHis lyra 
    RIGHT JOIN (qryLastMonthMtrHis pm 
        RIGHT JOIN qryCurrentMonthMtrHis cm ON (pm.Utility = cm.Utility) 
                                            AND (pm.MeterID = cm.MeterID))
        ON (lyra.Utility = cm.Utility) AND (lyra.MeterID = cm.MeterID)) 
ON (lyr.Utility = cm.Utility) AND (lyr.MeterID = cm.MeterID);
```